# How to change the value of XML node using java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

I ma trying to reset the value of a node but for some reason the change is not reflecting. I get the tag through `XPATH` but it doesn't set the value I give.
reqXML is the XML file

My Code

```
public static String changeProductVersion(String reqXML) {

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = null;
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource source = new InputSource();
        source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));
        document = builder.parse(source);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Element element = (Element) xPath.evaluate(NYPG3Constants.NY_PG3_RL, document, XPathConstants.NODE);

        if(element != null) {
            element.setTextContent("17.1.0");
            System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reqXML;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the structure of the XML file and what is the value of `NYPG3Constants.NY_PG3_RL` constant? Are you just setting the value of the node in the code or do you want to save it in the file? If you want to save it, there are no instructions for it in this code.

Comment: This is my XPATh and I want to set 17.1.0 instead of 14.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make some assumptions and changes because I don't know what your XML document looks like. But, the `Element` class extends `Node` and the `setTextContent` is a method on `Node`. What you need to update is the first child node, which is typically the text value of the element, but you should add some validation to make sure. Then, once you've updated the text value, you need to serialise the DOM back to whatever form it came from:

```
public static String changeProductVersion(String reqXML, String xpathExpression) {

    Document document = null;
    String updatedXML = null;

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));
        document = builder.parse(is);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Element element = (Element) xPath
                .compile(xpathExpression)
                .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);

        if(element != null) {
            NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();

            // Get the first node which should be the text value.
            // Add some validation to make sure Node == Node.TEXT_NODE.
            Node node = (Node) childNodes.item(0);
            node.setTextContent("17.1.0");
        }

        System.out.println("Updated element value: " + element.getTextContent());

        // Serialise the updated DOM
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        updatedXML = result.getWriter().toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(updatedXML);
    return updatedXML;
}
```

Comment: Yup it does what I am looking for, thank you so much.